# Java Regular Expression for matching "c/c++"

Tags: java, regex

i have these lines of codes to check user input a subject :

```
System.out.print("Enter a subject (java|c/c++|.net): ");
    i = sc.nextLine().trim();
    valid = i.matches("(java|c/c++|.net)");
    if(valid==false){
        System.out.println("Wrong Input");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Right Input");
    }
```

The problem is when i enter in c/c++ or .net as they show "Wrong Input".
I think it maybe the "/" and the "." in the regex . Could you guys help me ?

Comment: Mate... Look at the initialization of "valid". You cannot that. :|

Comment: Try with this: `"(java|c/c\\+\\+|\\.net)"`

Comment: Could you perhaps learn a little tiny bit about regular expressions before trying to use them?

Comment: `+` and `.` are special characters in regular expressions. Learn how to write regular expressions. See [Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and the API docs of [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: By the way you can write !valid instead of valid == false

Comment: Thanks you guys , i'm a just started learning java so could have lots of mistakes

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want is actually

```
java|c\/c\+\+|\.net
```

Because Java deals with regexes as strings, you'll need to double up the backslashes, yielding:

```
java|c\\/c\\+\\+|\\.net
```

Your code would then look like (with a few other improvements as well):

```
System.out.print("Enter a subject (java|c/c++|.net): ");
i = sc.nextLine().trim();
if(i.matches("java|c\\/c\\+\\+|\\.net")) {
    System.out.println("Right Input");
} else {
    System.out.println("Wrong Input");
}
```

[Demo and explanation of the regex on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zP0vD7/1)